# Recognizing new types from a library

Tags: java, compiler-construction

I am writing a compiler for a subset of the Java language and during writing the scanner i was wondering how do i recognize types that are not primitive but come from a library. For example the String type is not primitive in the Java language. In general, how do i recognize new types from libraries as "keywords" in the language without knowing them in advance. Thanks!

Comment: I misunderstood. Types will have known locations in the source based on the grammar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try getting through http://www.antlr.org/grammar/1152141644268/Java.g (pay attention to the `type` declaration and its usage) — it will give you some insight.

In brief, when you parse the source, you know where you expect to see a type, be it after modifiers in fields and methods, just before parameter names in formal parameter list, etc. And when you know that `String` is some type, you can check with `import` table to get a full name, and go find the actual class in the classpath.

Now, as Bart mentions in the comments (now deleted), the real resolution happens later in the pipeline. At the parsing stage, you only create a node saying that you have a `type` which is an `Identifier` which is *`String`.* So the answer at this moment would be, "you don't."

Update: try following [this thesis](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.127.4006), it should help you.

Comment: @alf when you say import table do you mean the list of all imports in that source code file. Also, when you say "and go find the actual class in the class path" does that mean go to that directory and check weather there exists a file name with the same name as the type(class) name and if it does exist then it is valid? thanks

Comment: @MikeG yes I do; no, you don't go to the directory right away: you have [a sequence of sources to use](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javac.html#searching).

Comment: @MikeG added a link to the "Distributed Java Compiler: Implementation and Evaluation" thesis. It has a proper introduction into standard Java compiler as well (for the current question, it's page 12).